# How to rewrite dynamic value in response bod using Charles Proxy

Tags: regex, charles-proxy, proxyman

I am new to Charles Proxy and Regular expression. I have been trying to rewrite feed an invalid session id to the mobile app to check the error handling.

We have the response body like this:

```
{
    “session_id": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3”
    "expiry_time": 42000,
    "refresh_token": "MiOiJodHRwOi8vdGVzdC5sdGEuYWNjb3Vr”
}
```

I am trying to rewrite the session_id and pass an invalid id using Charles rewrite

[Charles Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOUjy.png)

I have tried here in stackoverflow and couldn't find an answer. I am sure I am doing something wrong as a newbie. Any insight would be really appreciated

Comment: I voted you up Saro. Great job people down-voting on their first attempt in Stack Overflow. Anyways, you should be able to put in a breakpoint on your request in Charles Proxy and edit the response that is coming in before you complete the execution. If you are still having problems, reply here and I will provide a solution. Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kindness @droid-chris. I have managed to find the answer by myself.  May be this will be useful for newbie like me.

(“session”_id: ")([^"]+)

Comment: Post it as an answer so someone can up vote it.

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression `"session_id":\[(.*)\]` would not match the string `"session_id": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3"`.
Basically that regular expression is looking for something like this `"session_id":[any text]"`.

Try using this regex `"session_id": "(.*?)"`. It should match the format you're expecting in the response.

I hope this helps. Let me know if you need further information.